# "Similar questions" doesn't work for long questions

Tags: bug, similar-questions

"Similar questions" doesn't work for long questions. E.g.:

[image]

Tested on Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit) with the question

> Mismatching dimensions of input/output in the WaveNet model for text-to-speech generation? Mismatching dimensions of input/output in the WaveNet model for text-to-speech generation?

asked on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: If we search a single question double times.. Does it needs to show in similar question??

Comment: @SathiyaKumar The issue doesn't come from the fact the question is written twice.

Comment: So if we search a question with long character then the similar question is not showing any result??

Comment: @SathiyaKumar y